# ipython parallel cluster parallel decorator and higher order functions

Tags: python, ipython, python-decorators, ipython-parallel

I would like to take an existing function (from scikit-learn for example: specifically the "predict" function), and apply it using multiple cores to some dataset.

My first naive approach:

```
def parallel_predict(classifier):
    @dview.parallel(block=True)
    def predict( matrix ):
        return classifier.predict(matrix)
    return predict
```

Doesn't work (multiple cores don't start spinning up).  Is there a way to make this work?

Or some way to have "non-iterable" functions passed to a `@dview.parallel` function?

Comment: Are you trying to parallelise a single call to predict()? The simple methods of parallelisation are all basically ways to farm out multiple calls to a function so that they can run on different cores or different machines. Turning a serial function into a parallel one is usually more involved.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to parallelize a single call to predict().  @dview.parallel decorates a function so that when run on an iterable, it splits the iterable up and sends each of them to a different client:  which is what I want to do here.  Unfortunately, it seems to require that the arguments are ALL iterable.

Comment: Can you wrap the function call in a lambda that only exposes the iterable arguments you want to parallelise over?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of thoughts, both based on the [remote execution doc](https://minrk.github.io/scipy-tutorial-2011/basic_remote.html#). I'm used to the `@remote` decorator and not the `@parallel` one you've used, but hopefully they'll still apply to your case. (can't seem to get [that doc](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/parallel_multiengine.html) to load today, for some reason).

Is it the case that the remote execution is not working because the `classifier` module is not accessible on the engine? If so, this could be solved by adding an `import` statement to your decorated function explicitly,  by using `with dview.import_sync(): import classifier` (as per [this example](https://minrk.github.io/scipy-tutorial-2011/basic_remote.html#remote-imports)), or adding an `@require('classifier'):` decorator (from that same section of the doc). As far as the last option, not sure how multiple decorators interact (probably easiest to just give it a whack).

The second thought is that you could check for the remote exception(s) ([here's the doc on that](https://minrk.github.io/scipy-tutorial-2011/basic_remote.html#remote-exceptions)). This would be a lot more explicit than just getting nothing back. For example, something like:

```
x = e0.execute('1/0')
print x.metadata['error']

x = predict
print x.metadata['error']
```